# How do we pass two different parameters within xpath?

Tags: java, selenium

Can we parse two different Parameters with in xpath placed in map file and call it in function to identify an element using java?

xpath:

```
//table[@id='TemplateCreator']//td[contains(@id,'Template.1.2')]
```

In above xpath 1.2  is row.column value. So as I proceed I want to pass both row and column as parameter.  I am using hard coded xpath in my code as follows:

```
int row = 1;
int column = 2;
driver.findelement(By.Xpath("//table[@id='TemplateCreator']//td[contains(@id,'Template."+row+"."+column+"')]");
```

But, I want to call this xpath from Map file and pass row & column value as parameter. Something like this but is it possible using Java?

```
string template = //table[@id='TemplateCreator']//td[contains(@id,'Template.<identifier_row>.<identifier_column>')]
driver.findelement(By.Xpath(template+row+column);
```

Comment: The XPath is just a string... you just substitute whatever variables in it just like you would any other string.

Answer (score 1):

try as follows:

```
 String template = "//table[@id='TemplateCreator']//td[contains(@id,'Template.%d.%d')]"; //read template from Map file
    int row=1;
    int column=1;
    String after = String.format(template, row, column);
    System.out.println("after replacing: " + after);
```

In Map file, store template as follows:

```
//table[@id='TemplateCreator']//td[contains(@id,'Template.%d.%d')]
```

so, later you can use `String.format` to format the string.